# How to add box-sizing: border-box to all HTML elements using TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

What's the equivalent for this in TailwindCSS?

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: what's stoping you from doing just as above ?

Comment: Add it to the preflight? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#extending-preflight

Comment: box-sizing: border-box; maybe because you have written the box-sizing wrong?

Comment: Please, can you explain how?

Answer (score 6):

Tailwind already has such stylings in [preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) - see compiled [stylesheet](https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.1.8/src/css/preflight.css).

```css
/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
}
```

So there is no need to add it unless you've disabled preflights.

However Tailwind's equivalent class name will be `border-box` - see [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

`box-border` (Tailwind) is the equivalent to `box-sizing: border-box;` (CSS).

If you want to apply this style to all your elements, you should use `@layer base` in your `main.css`. This way you apply styles to specific elements, it's mostly used for elements such as `h1` and `p` but it should work the same way with `*`.

Here's the part in the documentation explaining it: [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles).

main.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  * {
    @apply box-border;
  } 
}
```